# Is every monotonic simple function a step function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, monotone-functions, simple-functions

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a **simple function**, that is, $f (x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \mathbb{1}_{A_i}(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, where each $a_i$ is a constant, each $A_i$ is a measurable set and $\mathbb{1}_{A_i}$ denotes the indicator function of the set $A_i$. If each $A_i$ is an interval, then $f$ is called a **step function**. While every step function is clearly a simple function, the reverse is not true. For instance, $f(x) = \mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ is a simple function but not a step function ($\mathbb{Q}$ being the set of rational numbers).

Now, suppose that $f$ is a **non-decreasing** simple function, that is, $x \leq y$ implies $f(x) \leq f(y)$. Is $f$ necessarily a step function in this case? (I can't find a counterexample.)

Comment: Are you insisting that the summation is finite in your definition? If so, $f(x) = floor(x)$ is non-decreasing and not a step function (takes infinitely many values).

Comment: @jugglingmike, the summation ought to be finite because that's part of the definition of a simple function.  OP wants a simple function that's not a step function.  How is $\operatorname{floor}(x)$ defined on all of $\Bbb R$ a simple function?

Comment: My apologies, I had the implications confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f$ be a simple function, so that its image is a finite set $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$.

If $f$ is non-decreasing, then each set $I_j := f^{-1}(a_j)$ is connected, hence it is an interval.
Namely, if $x_1, x_2 \in I_j$, with $x_1 < x_2$, then 
$$
a_j = f(x_1) \leq f(x) \leq f(x_2) = a_j,
\qquad
\forall x\in [x_1, x_2],
$$
i.e. $[x_1, x_2]\subset I_j$.